# Book outline in custom form

Tags: 7, forms, nodes

I am creating a custom form which creates new nodes of type 'book'. I have been able to get the "book outline" to render on my form using

```
$nid = $node->nid ='nid';    
module_load_include('inc', 'book', 'book.pages');
book_outline_form($form,$form_state,$node);
_book_add_form_elements($form,$form_state, $node);
```

My issue is when i select the drop-down for Book, it does not have "create a new book" as an option[image]

Can someone help me with this issue? Has anyone experienced this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I got it to work!** My issue was that `$nid = $node->nid ='nid'` should have been set to `$nid = $node->nid ='new'`.

I also added `module_load_include('inc', 'book', 'book.pages');` to call the function book_outline_form();